# How to create a DateTime object?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have three integers: Hours, Minutes, and Seconds.

I want to create a `DateTime` object with System.Date and Time provided by the above three variables.

Comment: Does it need to be today's date, or a timespan ?

Comment: To add to what @Stephen said, .NET documentation can be found at the [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/).

Comment: plus 1 its not a bad question, Don't know why you down voted

Answer (score 33):

Check out MSDN and have a look at the [constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.datetime.aspx) that exists for `DateTime`,  you'll find out that this is possible:

```
var theDate = new DateTime (DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, hours, minute, second);
```

Comment: Posted the same thing 10 seconds later! Voted to delete mine :)

Comment: This could potentially supply the wrong date if the clock goes past midnight inbetween evaluating DateTime.Today.Year and DateTime.Today.Day.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`DateTime.Today`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) to get the current date at midnight, and add the hours you need by using a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx), which is a good way to represent hours of the day:

```
TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(12, 20, 20); // hours, minutes, seconds
DateTime todayWithTime = DateTime.Today + time;
```

See also:

- [TimeSpan(Int32, Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk8a3558.aspx)
- [operator +(DateTime,TimeSpan)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_addition.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

See [DateTime.Today](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) and this [DateTime constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130.aspx)

```
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, 10, 39, 30);
```

Comment: Maybe I come late , but you must have meant `today.Day` as third parameter. Maybe a typo.

Answer (score 1):

you have a constructor that takes:

```
DateTime(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)
```

Initializes a new instance of the DateTime structure to the specified year, month, day, hour, minute, and second.

Answer (score 1):

or you can simply parse the hours/mins/secs with `DateTime.Parse()` which will generate the current date automatically (this is also written in the documentation)