# Any way to get a DateTime object from this string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any way to get a DateTime from:

```
Mon Mar 04 2013 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: Yes.......................

Comment: I tried Convert.ToDateTime(dateStr); I really have no idea what the format is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the parse datetime.

```
datetime dt = new datetime("Mon Mar 04 2013 18:00:00");
```

or

```
dt = DateTime.Parse("Mon Mar 04 2013 18:00:00");
```

if its already in a string.  You may want to put it in a try catch because if it doesn't work.

those methods will give you a new datetime object which you can still manipulate.

If you wanted to print it back out in that particular order you would need to put it in
something like this.

```
dt.ToString("ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

If you need anymore instruction on datetime objects you can always check out

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format

or

[How to create a DateTime object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578931/how-to-create-a-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to go into too terribly deep detail, but If you know that that string is always going to be like that, you can parse it using

```
string[] inputString = myString.Split(' ')
```

and you can take the parts of that, and format it into a known date-time format

```
string dateString = String.Format({0}:{1}:{2}, myString[0], myString[i], myString[j]);
```

at which point you can use the

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dateString)
```

to get the actual dateTime

Comment: It's an ugly solution, but the data coming in is just as ugly :)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) or [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx)

Something like this... You might have to play with it, I haven't tested this, but it gives you the general idea, I think.

```
var str = "Mon Mar 04 2013 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss GMTzzzzz (Eastern Standard Time)", str);
```

You might have to trim off that "(Eastern Standard Time)" bit at the end. I'm not sure how you could cover that with the format string if it changes from string to string.

Answer (score -1):

Use the built in convert method, It should be able to get that

```
Convert.ToDateTime(dateStr);
```

Comment: String not recognized as valid.

Comment: That was the exception you got? So the string is not something Convert.ToDateTime recognizes. You will need to massage the string a little bit more. Where is the data coming from? Can you get it in a nicer format?